# EFI won't load linux kernel in LFS

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, uefi, boot-loader, lfs

Lately, I've been building an [LFS [Linux From Scratch]](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable) system for my [Raspberry Pi Single Board Computer](https://raspberrypi.org), and I'm currently on the very last step. I'm attempting to compile [Linux 5.15 from the Raspberry Pi official Repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux), but every time I install the kernel and reboot, the following happens:

1. Rainbow splash screen appears [READING FAT32 PARTITION]
2. Raspberry Pi Logo appears [UEFI FIRMWARE LOADED]
3. GRUB2 Boot menu appears
4. This appears:

```
EFI stub: Booting Linux Kernel...
EFI stub: Using DTB from configuration table
EFI stub: Exiting boot services...
```

And that's it. The boot process stops and remains stuck there forever. The most likely problem I can think of is invalid kernel configuration. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Hmm... Is the default RPi kernel configured in such a way that expects an `initramfs` to be available for early loading modules to support its hardware? I do own a RPi, it's around here somewhere, still in the box, and I don't really screw around with those types of boot configurations myself, so I would expect a little more output if that were the case... a panic, an error message, something... maybe something to consider though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly solve my problem, but here's what I did to get past that screen:

1. Download the .deb file for the Raspberry Pi Linux Kernel
2. Extract the contents of it using `ar`
3. Untar `data.tar.xz`
4. Copy and paste `vmlinuz-5.10.0-19-arm64` and `System.map-5.10.0-19-arm64` into `/boot` of my LFS system
5. Reboot

Copying-and-pasting a kernel is gernerally a HORRIBLE idea, but unbelievably, it actually got me past that screen. I still have a kernel panic, but that deserves another question.